# spring-boot-maven-plugin build-info.properties

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-3, spring-boot-maven-plugin, application.properties

**How can I use properties from build-info.properties in application.properties?**

pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

build-info.properties is correctly generated:

```
cat app/target/classes/META-INF/build-info.properties 
build.artifact=foo-app
build.group=org.springframework.boot
build.name=foo-app
build.time=2021-10-13T12\:46\:08.326Z
build.version=9.9.0-9-5f12d7cd-bugfix_bar_3123_branch_name_123-dirty
```

How can I use them i application.properties?

```
foo=@project.artifactId@-sew2-san-@build.artifact@-${build.artifact}
```

only @project.artifactId@ is resolved, neither @build.artifact@ nor ${build.artifact} is resolved.

**Is it possible to use properties from build-info.properties in application.properties?**

Comment: Why do you like to do that? Why do you need build information in your `application.properties` and for what purpose?

Comment: @khmarbaise I would like to use ${build.name} as part of another property (some label) in application.properties eg some.label=${env}-${build.name}-label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add:

```ini
spring.config.import=classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties
```

to your `application.properties` file then interpolation with an expression like `${build.artifact}` will start to work.

(Spring is loading build-info.properties with a weird manual way as you can see e.g. here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/info/ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.java)